# Caffeine not working on Kubunte 18.10

Tags: kubuntu, kde, kde5, caffeine

Tried to install caffeine, and it's not working.

I have Kubuntu 18.10, KDE Plazma 5.14.4

Do this way

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get install caffeine
```

And from default Kubunto repository `ubuntu-cosmic-universe` with the same result.

Caffiene version on both variant was `2.9.4-1`

After launch caffeine-indicator and activate from tray.

If I try to run caffeine from KDE menu, nothing happened, no window opened.

If run from console its runs without any output and without window, but don't work.

Comment: [That ppa](https://launchpad.net/~caffeine-developers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) seems **not** to be for *buntu versions higher than 17.10. The last successful build was **93 weeks** ago.

Comment: @DKBose So there is no version for my Kubuntu?

Comment: Uninstall the version you installed and its ppa. Then just install caffeine from the standard repos. Run `apt policy caffeine` to see that it's available for your system: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man1/caffeine.1.html

Comment: @DK It was the first that I do. The same result. And there is the same versions. 2.9.4-1

Comment: Please edit your question to provide that information that the repo version doesn't work.

Comment: @DKBose Added this information.

Comment: No window opens when caffeine runs, and it does not do anything unless an application runs full screen. To control it manually install caffeine-indicator.

Comment: @Organic It is installs already with Coffeine for me. I tried with it first.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old, so I'll answer it for Kubuntu 20.04

1. Remove the outdated package:

   ```
   sudo apt remove --purge caffeine && sudo apt autoremove
   ```
2. Remove the outdated PPA:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
   ```
3. Install the `caffeine` package from the official repositories:

   ```
   sudo apt install caffeine
   ```
4. Open a terminal and run:

   ```
   caffeine-indicator & exit
   ```
5. Wait for about 5 seconds and you should see the indicator in your system icons widget.

If it doesn't work, try to use `caffeine-indicator &` instead (without exit). This will let you see the logs. If you're able to see them, please edit your question and add them there.

I tried this on my laptop and everything seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I do not use Kubuntu now, and can not test you answer to check is it working to set as answer. But get my +